# How to publish mysql table insertions as a SMS

Tags: mysql, database, sms, twilio

I am using mysql 5.7 with ubuntu 14.04.

I have a table where I want to track and publish the specific column as a SMS notification whenever a new row is inserted.

I did some research on mysql triggers but I am not able to find the exact solution.

BTW I have a twilio account in my hand that can be used for sending SMS or by using an sms gateway like *number@smsgateway.com*

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.